# Ajax function to retrieve list of items to C# WebMethod in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have the following list of items in a Asp.net page (example):

```
<ul id="lstFruits">
    <li id="fruit" value="1">Banana</li>
    <li id="fruit" value="2">Apple</li>
    <li id="fruit" value="3">Melon</li>
    <li id="fruit" value="4">Pineapple</li>
    <li id="fruit" value="5">Grape</li>
</ul>
```

I made this list editable in the page, so I would like to build an ajax/javascript function to call a C# webmethod in CodeBehind that sends this list as parameter. This function would be called though a `asp:LinkButton`.

My questions are: how could write this ajax function? (I did some examples, but without success) How can I link this function with the button?

**Edit:**

I tried to do this ajax function:

```
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@FruitsList.aspx/SaveFruitsList",
            data: "{" + 'fruits:' + lstFruits + "}",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Fruits saved successively.");
            },
        });
    });
```

The button is:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Save" />
```

**Note:** I tried to use the `OnClick` event, but didn't work.

In codebehind (FruitsList.aspx.cs), I'm not sure how to define the webmethod parameters. The idea would be receive a list (or array) of ids corresponding to the fruits, and save them in the database.

Comment: Why don't you post up what you tried and show us where you got stuck?  I bet we could point you in the right direction.

Comment: I wouldn't like to show some parts of my code, but I think I can adapt it, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your data parameter to this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({fruits: lstFruits}),
```

Also your LinkButton onclick wont work because it is a asp server control. The ID will render differently, and it will try and do a postback on click.

Try changing the link button to have a onclientclick with a false return to prevent the postback:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" onClientClick="someFunctionName();return false;" CssClass="button" Text="Save" />
```

Then replace the onclick function with someFunctionName() so it calls it when the linkbutton is clicked and will not postback

Comment: Didn't work. The browser console said: "Uncaught ReferenceError: lstFruits is not defined".

Comment: how are you defining lstFruits? You have not included that anywhere?

Comment: Originally, lstFruits is defined as a [asp:BulletedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist(v=vs.110).aspx), but when the page is loaded in the browser, it transforms in the code above.

Comment: Sorry, but I believe you need to investigate javascript/jquery a lot more. Firstly javascript does not understand lstFruit as anything, its looking for a variable called lstFruit which does not exist. The jquery representation of your rendered element is $("#lstFruit") even then, you can not pass this into a jquery ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the comments you have applied to my previous answer. You need to get the list of list element ids. With jquery you can do this inside your button click function before the ajax call:

```
var lstFruits = [];
    alert("hello");
    $("#lstFruits li").each(function() {
  lstFruits.push($(this).text());

});
```

That will place all the fruits (bannana apple etc) into an array to pass into the webmethod.

Your webmethod should look like this in c#. declare the using at the top to use webmethods.

```
using System.Web.Services;

[webmethod()]
public static string SaveFruitsList(List<string> fruits) {
 do something
}
```